# Selecting exactly one item from each condition of the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
  topic.title, 
  topic.content_id, 
  topic.thumbnail_icon, 
  text.description 
FROM 
  mps_contents AS topic, 
  mps_contents AS text 
WHERE 
  topic.featured = '1' AND 
  topic.active = '1' AND 
  topic.page_id = (SELECT page_id 
                     FROM mps_pages 
                    WHERE page_short_name = 'services' 
                       OR page_short_name = 'questions_faqs') AND 
  text.section_id = (SELECT section_id 
                       FROM mps_sections 
                      WHERE section_short_name = 'page_text') AND 
  text.page_id = topic.content_id AND 
  topic.resource_type = 'subpage' AND 
  text.resource_type = 'text' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

**EDIT:**
This is MySQL

What I want to do really is select 1 featured item from `services` and 1 featured item from `questions`. However this query will select 2 featured items from either `services` or `questions`!

I know that one option is to make a `UNION` and doing `LIMIT 1` on both queries of the `UNION` but that would mean I would have to duplicate 90% of the query. Can I do this without having to resort to `UNION`s?

Comment: I am doing this in MySQL. InnoDB tables. Is that what 'flavor' means?

Comment: A UNION is one query; I don't see how to get what you want without using a UNION.

Comment: Oh.. You are right, but a `UNION` would require me to repeat 90% of the original query just to specify a different condition. I was thinking if I can avoid doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I believe unless you re-design/normalize the table, you will always end up repeating the query to some extent.

If all you want to avoid union, you can re-write

```
  topic.page_id = (SELECT page_id 
                 FROM mps_pages 
                WHERE page_short_name = 'services' 
                   OR page_short_name = 'questions_faqs')
```

to

```
topic.page_id = (SELECT page_id 
                 FROM mps_pages 
                 WHERE page_short_name = 'services' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
                   OR 
topic.page_id = (SELECT page_id 
                 FROM mps_pages 
                 WHERE page_short_name = 'questions_faqs' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

I don't think there will be too much performance boost though as rand() run twice

Comment: I see. Well in that case I think I'll simply go for the readability of this query rather than performance.